# Unable to connect to Sharepoint in Salesforce using File-connect

Tags: sharepoint, salesforce, customization, external, visualforce

I want to view my Sharepoint documnets in salesforce using "File Connect" introduced in Winter15 release for connecting to External Data source but i am facing a problem to connect to sharepoint. I have used the follwing link for Set Up Salesforce Files Connect :

http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/api_cti/release-notes/rn_chatter_files_connect_setup.htm and followed the steps below :

1) First, enable Files Connect, and let users access related
    external data sources

a) Enable Files Connect for your organization.

b) Let users access Files Connect data sources.

2) For cloud-based data sources, create an authentication provider, and then define the source

a) Create a SharePoint Online authentication provider.

b) Define a SharePoint Online external data source for Files Connect.

But when completing the step2 b) and clicking on Start Authentication Flow on Save as checked and saving it takes me to sharepoint login page and when logged in to sharepoint following error occurs:

**The query String "redirect_uri" is missing or invalid**

I have checked lots of sites but unable to correct fix this issue.If anyone has knowledge please,please share it with me as soon as possible .

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that either your Salesforce auth provider is not correctly configured or that your SharePoint Online app is not correctly configured.

I would recommend opening a ticket with the Salesforce support team so that they have a look at your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

am also working on this
i faced an issue
when woking with external data source:

can u let me know what is to be filled in this field "Authentication Provider"--which is a look up field when i click on this nothing appears.
and my authentication protcol is Oauth.